# XPATH expression to find node

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm having troubles forming proper xpath expression to find data in xml similar to following:

```
<record>
<datafield tag="675" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">791.221.4(71+44+469+450)(086.82)</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">791.2</subfield>
    <subfield code="s">791.2</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">791.2</subfield>
    <subfield code="v">UDCMRF 2006</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="702" ind1="1" ind2="1">
    <subfield code="3">39609187</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Cronenberg</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">David</subfield>
    <subfield code="f">1943-</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">300</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">690</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="702" ind1="0" ind2="1">
    <subfield code="3">16448611</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Suschitzky</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Peter</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">600</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="702" ind1="0" ind2="1">
    <subfield code="3">8497763</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Shore</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">Howard</subfield>
    <subfield code="4">230</subfield>
</datafield>
</record>
```

How to build an expression that basically says: search datafields with tag value 702 and return me surname and name of person that has value 300 in subfield with code 4 - so that the answer in this case would be Cronenberg David?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in a shorter XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datafield[@tag="702"][./subfield[@code="4" and .="300"]]
```

Will select the desired datafield element.

```
datafield[@tag="702"][./subfield[@code="4" and .="300"]]/subfield[@code="a" or @code="b"]/text()
```

Will return `['Cronenberg', 'David']` assuming that the subfields appear in that order in the document

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[@tag=702 and subfield[@code=4]=300]
         /subfield[@code='a' or @code='b']/text()
```

Comment: So, another way to skin the cat :) Works as well, cheers mate.

Comment: @Ales, You are welcome, mate -- I only posted this because it is slightly shorter and more streamlined -- one doesn't need to use `./` and `"./subfield[@code="4" and .="300"` can simply be written as: `subfield[@code=4]=300`